# Exporting code in Jenkins file for build pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have couple of build pipelines configured in Jenkins. Is there a way to export them into `Jenkinsfile`s so that it can be checked in source code (I want to use it pipeline as a code).

Thanks!

Comment: How did you "configure" those? Using free-style jobs and the web interface? Then: no.

Comment: Using web interface.

Comment: Nothing automatically as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pipeline as code steps to add a Jenkinsfile to your codebase. Please refer the below link.

https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/

You can also look out for Declarative Pipeline as well.

https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/03/declarative-pipeline-ga/

If you have already have the pipeline steps, please create a Jenkinsfile(by copying the contents of the pipeline code) at the root folder of your repo and create a Pipeline/MultiBranch Pipeline/Github Organization job based on your convenience.

Please let me know if you would require further information on the same.

Comment: Yeah. I need to write. But I was wondering any automated way since I created my pipeline using web interface.

Comment: I am of the opinion that you had used jenkins blue ocean pipeline editor plugin to automate the tasks. If you had used it, please copy the contents of the script(that it generates) to the Jenkinsfile. You can find the code by navigating in the below order:                                                                                       Open Blue ocean(on top half of the page) --> PipelineEditor --> Load/Save --> Code

Comment: I have not used BlueOcean but standard Jenkins Build pipeline plugin. The subsequent jobs are triggered from Parameterized build plugin in post build section.

Comment: You can start using the Blue ocean pipeline editor or Jenkins Declarative/Scripted Pipeline(which ever suits you best). The links to get started are as follows:                                                                                                 https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/   https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: Got it. It means manually I need to write syntax in Jenkins file.